# Problem backing up my iPhone to my Mac, the iPhone icon does not appear in iTunes

Tags: iphone, itunes, backup, imac

I have an 2010 iMac running High Sierra. I have iTunes version 12.8.2.3 and iOS version 12.3.1.  I want to backup my iPhone to my computer using iTunes.

In the past I could connect my iPhone to my computer and when I started iTunes the iPhone icon would appear on the left side on the iTunes screen. I would select the iPhone and then back it up to either my computer or to iCloud.

Now, however, the iPhone does not appear in iTunes. How do I backup my iPhone to my computer?

Comment: @David, As a **hard reset wipes data, this is not the first thing to do!!!** Do a soft reset first!

Comment: @user3439894 how do I do a soft reset on my iPone 6?

Comment: jmh, A soft reset it just turning the device off and then back on. https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201559. or https://support.apple.com/guide/iphone/force-restart-iphone-iph8903c3ee6/ios

Comment: @user3439894 The soft reset alone seems to have solved my problem. I should have thought of that myself. If you want to write this up as an answer I'll accept it.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @user3439894 I erred in calling for a "hard reset, and will delete my comment. I was thinking about the mid-level procedure of holding the Home and Sleep/Wake buttons simultaneously, until the Apple logo appears. The Settings > Erase All Content and Settings procedure is indeed a more serious step. In my defense, there is no consistency from Apple or the aftermarket about the names given to the three procedures: 1) hold Sleep/Wake button then use slider to power off; 2) hold Sleep/Wake and Home buttons until Apple logo appears; and 3) Settings > Erase all Content and Settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First try a soft reset on the iPhone.

> **Restart your iPhone 8 or earlier or iPod touch**
>
> 1. Press and hold the Top (or Side) button until the power off slider appears.
> 2. Drag the slider to turn your device completely off.*
> 3. After your device turns off, press and hold the Top (or Side) button again until you see the Apple logo.
>
> * With iOS 11 or later, you can turn off your device by going to Settings > General> Shut Down.

<sub>Source: [Restart your iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201559)</sub>

Note that restarting the computer may also be necessary if the soft reset doesn't fix the issue.

---

If a soft reset and restarting the computer doesn't fix it, then you may have to do a hard reset on the device. If so, have a look at: [How to erase your iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201274)